# how to achieve following using css ( digits input )

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve following feature:

[image]

It's an input box, has 4 digits, once clicked, user can input 4 digits.
It's part of a mobile app.

Currently what I have achieved is : [example](http://jsfiddle.net/8PTp5/), note that for some reason, 
`outline: none;` works fine in my app but not work in this jsFiddle example.

My question is how to draw the 3 separation bar and also display those digits 
just fit their position within it?

Is it achievable using css?

below are code:

```
<form id="login" class="ui-shadow-around ui-corner-all-input" data-enhance="false">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <span>
            <input type="tel" name="retailer_pin" maxlength="4" class="numbersOnly" required="" placeholder="" style="outline: none;">
        </span>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="submitHidden">
</form>
```

css:

```
.ui-corner-all-input {
    -webkit-background-clip: padding;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    -webkit-border-radius: .6em /*{global-radii-blocks}*/;
    border-radius: .6em /*{global-radii-blocks}*/;
    width: 35%;height: 3.5em; margin: 0 auto; margin-bottom: 44px;
    margin-top: 24px; 
}
.ui-shadow-around {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px /*{global-box-shadow-size}*/ rgba(0,0,0,0.4) /*{global-box-shadow-color}*/;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px /*{global-box-shadow-size}*/ rgba(0,0,0,0.4) /*{global-box-shadow-color}*/;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px /*{global-box-shadow-size}*/ rgba(0,0,0,0.4) /*{global-box-shadow-color}*/;
    border: 1px #b6b6b6 solid;
}
*:not(input):not(textarea) {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}
FORM[data-enhance="false"] INPUT, textarea {
    outline: none;
}
FORM[data-enhance="false"] SPAN {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 10px 0 0px;
    text-align: left;
}
.submitHidden {
    visiblity: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: unless you want a complicated mess of html elements and css, probably you want to do multiple separate inputs, like @Ed_Zamrik said, and use Javascript to submit/input when submitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this:

HTML:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td><input class="clock" type="text" maxlength="1" size="1" onkeyup="next(2)"></td>
  <td><input id="2" class="clock" type="text" maxlength="1" size="1" onkeyup="next(3)"></td>
  <td><input id="3" class="clock" type="text" maxlength="1" size="1" onkeyup="next(4)"></td>
  <td><input id="4" class="clock" type="text" maxlength="1" size="1"></td>
</tr>
```

CSS:

```
.clock {
  color:darkgray;
  border-style:none;
  width:40px;
  height:60px;
  font-size:60px;
}

td{
  border:2px solid darkgray  
}
table {
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function next(next) {
  document.getElementById(next).focus();
}
```

Link: http://jsbin.com/uhaHunuq/1/edit?html,output

Comment: @Robert Replace it with `border-right: 2px solid darkgray;` if you want the border only on the right

Comment: works in browser, but doesn't trigger virtual keyboard pop up...I am using JQuery mobile

Comment: What device are you using? What browser?

Comment: iPhone5, it's an jQuery mobile project, using phonegap

Comment: This breaks backspace button

Answer (score 3):

Here is my take on the problem.

It uses a proper input element (please don't make the life of your users harder than it already is) and a transparent background to render 4 blocks in the background.

```css
.input-widget {
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-left: 1rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.input-widget .input {
    width: 8rem;
    font-size: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
}

.input-widget .input::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
.input-widget .input::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}

.input-widget .digit-background {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

.input-widget .digit-background .digit {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

.input-widget .digit-background .digit::before {
    content: '0';
    color: lightgray;
    background-color: currentColor;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1px;
    margin: -1px 4px 0 -1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-widget">
   <input type="number" max="9999" class="input" value="01234">
   <div class="digit-background">
     <div class="digit"></div>
     <div class="digit"></div>
     <div class="digit"></div>
     <div class="digit"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And a SCSS version is here: https://jsfiddle.net/cburgmer/0xgtdyLj/1/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use four text input items and put them in a small table. With `JavaScript`, make each text box take one character and give the focus state to the next text box. The lines could be done with the table border and box. Use the `CSS` to hide the text box frame.

Comment: Don't forget the `maxlength` attribute, which limits the amount of characters the user can type.

Comment: Hi, I found, .focus() doesn't pop up virtual keyboard, any reasons?